# Custom Query with spring CrudRepository

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am learning the JPA framework but I cannot do a custom query.

I already did this tutorial :
https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-jpa/
And now I want to do a custom query for example `"SELECT firstName,lastName FROM Customer"`

I tried with :

```
public interface CustomerRepository extends CrudRepository<Customer, Long> {

    @Query("SELECT firstName,lastName FROM Customer")
    Iterable<Customer> findAll();

    List<Customer> findByLastName(String lastName);
}
```

But I get `java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to hello.Customer`

My code is the same as in the tutorial except that on 33 row of Application I call

```
for (Customer customer : repository.findAll()) {
                log.info(customer.toString());
            }
```

To test my custom query

I expect to log me the data for every customer but it throw me an exception:
`java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to hello.Customer`

Comment: delete the query annotation. `@Query("SELECT firstName,lastName FROM Customer")`

Comment: This query actually returns list of tuples `Object[]`, not `Customer`s

Comment: You should post your entity Customer and the table Customer to see if everything match. But it seems that you don't return a Customer. Try changing your sql this way :  @Query("SELECT c FROM Customer c")
    Iterable<Customer> findAll(); or remove it completely because findAll is implemented already in crudrepository

Comment: I want to make a query that select only firstName and lastName not all data
@XavierBouclet You can view all this code into the tutorial that i gave

Answer (score 2):

You could use 
`@Query("SELECT new your.package.Customer(firstName,lastName) FROM Customer")`

to obtain the object you want. If you want an object with only firstname and lastname, I would use another object.